# Postgres get the exact row count of all tables without using vacuum

Tags: postgresql, database-administration

I want to get the number of rows in all tables of a postgres database. I analyzed and found out ways like , count(*) for all tables - which seems very slow for larger tables. Reading statistics from pg_stat_user_tables - But that require 'vacuum' to be run on a database. Do we have better ways for finding this..I need to find the exact row count of all tables

Comment: The **only** way to get the _exact_ row is to use `select count(*)`

Comment: we can also do this by running vacuum on our database and then getting the count from statistics right. Sometimes vacuum also takes lots of time , so is there a possibility to find the row_count in some other ways

Comment: Again, the only way to get the **exact** row count is to use `select count(*)`. The row count `vacuum` "calculates" is still an estimate.

Comment: can you explain how is it approximate and I cannot use it when I want to get the exact count